# Assigning a function to angular ui-router `onEnter` doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

The following works.

```
onEnter: function isAuthed($state, isLogin) {
    ...
}
```

But the following doesn't.

```
function isAuthed($state, isLogin) {
    ...
}

onEnter: isAuthed($state, isLogin)
```

Why? Shouldn't they be interchangeable?

Answer (score 1):

It's because when you write `onEnter: isAuthed($state, isLogin)` you don't assign the function to the event.

To do it, don't repeat the parameter in the affectation :

```
function isAuthed($state, isLogin) {
    ...
}

onEnter: isAuthed
```